# Pebble watch face crashing on exit

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I am making a very simple watch face my my Pebble. I have three text layers. One shows the time, on shows the date, and one shows the progress indicator for the day.

Whenever I press a button to go to the menu or go to another watch face, the app crashes. I thought that perhaps I wasn't destroying something in the deinit process, but I've double checked and can't find anything. Here is the code (excuse some of the messiness, I was in the process of debugging something else):

```
#include <pebble.h>

static Window *s_main_window;
static TextLayer *s_time_layer;
static TextLayer *s_date_layer;
static TextLayer *s_progress_layer;

static void update_time() {
  // Get a tm structure
  time_t temp = time(NULL); 
  struct tm *tick_time = localtime(&temp);

  // Create a long-lived buffer
  static char buffer[] = "00:00";
  static char date_buffer[] = "00/00/00";
  static char progress_buffer[24];

  int hour = 0;

  if(tick_time->tm_hour == 0) { hour = 1; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 1) { hour = 1; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 2) { hour = 1; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 3) { hour = 2; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 4) { hour = 2; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 5) { hour = 3; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 6) { hour = 3; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 7) { hour = 4; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 8) { hour = 4; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 9) { hour = 5; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 10) { hour = 5; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 11) { hour = 6; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 12) { hour = 6; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 13) { hour = 7; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 14) { hour = 7; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 15) { hour = 8; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 16) { hour = 8; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 17) { hour = 9; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 18) { hour = 9; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 19) { hour = 10; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 20) { hour = 10; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 21) { hour = 11; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 22) { hour = 11; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 23) { hour = 12; }
  else if(tick_time->tm_hour == 24) { hour = 12; }

  const char src1[] = "•";
  const char src2[] = "• •";
  const char src3[] = "• • •";
  const char src4[] = "• • • •";
  const char src5[] = "• • • • •";
  const char src6[] = "• • • • • •";
  const char src7[] = "• • • • • • •";
  const char src8[] = "• • • • • • • •";
  const char src9[] = "• • • • • • • • •";
  const char src10[] = "• • • • • • • • • •";
  const char src11[] = "• • • • • • • • • • •";
  const char src12[] = "• • • • • • • • • • • •";

  switch(hour){
    case 1:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src1);
      break;
    case 2:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src2);
      break;
    case 3:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src3);
      break;
    case 4:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src4);
      break;
    case 5:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src5);
      break;
    case 6:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src6);
      break;
    case 7:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src7);
      break;
    case 8:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src8);
      break;
    case 9:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src9);
      break;
    case 10:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src10);
      break;
    case 11:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src10);
      break;
    case 12:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src10);
      break;
    default:
      strcpy(progress_buffer, src1);
      break;
  }

  // Write the current hours and minutes into the buffer
  if(clock_is_24h_style() == true) {
    // Use 24 hour format
    strftime(buffer, sizeof("00:00"), "%H:%M", tick_time);
    strftime(date_buffer, sizeof("00/00/00"), "%D", tick_time);
  } else {
    // Use 12 hour format
    strftime(buffer, sizeof("00:00"), "%I:%M", tick_time);
    strftime(date_buffer, sizeof("00/00/00"), "%D", tick_time);
  }

  if (!clock_is_24h_style() && (buffer[0] == '0')) {
    memmove(buffer, &buffer[1], sizeof(buffer) - 1);
  }

  // Display this time on the TextLayer
  text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer, buffer);
  text_layer_set_text(s_date_layer, date_buffer);
  text_layer_set_text(s_progress_layer, progress_buffer);
}

static void tick_handler(struct tm *tick_time, TimeUnits units_changed) {
  update_time();
}

static void main_window_load(Window *window) {

  window_set_background_color(s_main_window, GColorBlack);

  // Create time TextLayer
  s_time_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 45, 144, 55));
  text_layer_set_background_color(s_time_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_text_color(s_time_layer, GColorWhite);

  // Improve the layout to be more like a watchface
  text_layer_set_font(s_time_layer, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_BITHAM_42_BOLD));
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_time_layer, GTextAlignmentCenter);

  // Add it as a child layer to the Window's root layer
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_time_layer));



  // Create date TextLayer
  s_date_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 95, 144, 40));
  text_layer_set_background_color(s_date_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_text_color(s_date_layer, GColorWhite);

  // Improve the layout to be more like a watchface
  text_layer_set_font(s_date_layer, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_24_BOLD));
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_date_layer, GTextAlignmentCenter);

  // Add it as a child layer to the Window's root layer
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_date_layer));



  // Create progress TextLayer
  s_progress_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 143, 144, 35));
  text_layer_set_background_color(s_progress_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_text_color(s_progress_layer, GColorWhite);

  // Improve the layout to be more like a watchface
  text_layer_set_font(s_progress_layer, fonts_get_system_font(FONT_KEY_GOTHIC_14));
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_progress_layer, GTextAlignmentCenter);

  // Add it as a child layer to the Window's root layer
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_progress_layer));

  // Make sure the time is displayed from the start
  update_time();
}

static void main_window_unload(Window *window) {
  // Destroy TextLayer
  text_layer_destroy(s_time_layer);
  text_layer_destroy(s_date_layer);
  text_layer_destroy(s_progress_layer);
}

static void init() {
  // Create main Window element and assign to pointer
  s_main_window = window_create();

  // Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
  window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  });

  // Show the Window on the watch, with animated=true
  window_stack_push(s_main_window, true);

  // Register with TickTimerService
  tick_timer_service_subscribe(MINUTE_UNIT, tick_handler);
}

static void deinit() {
  // Destroy Window
  window_destroy(s_main_window);
  tick_timer_service_unsubscribe();
}

int main(void) {
  init();
  app_event_loop();
  deinit();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error outputted when debugging?

Comment: In the app logs I got the following message each time the app crashes:


`[ERROR] ault_handling.c:77: App fault! {66ba5de5-f8c2-44ec-ae28-58b801c6863c} PC: 0x8016e14 LR: 0x8016e95`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the buffer size of progress_buffer, and the watchface stopped crashing. I found the value to be a minimum of 37 for the code to work. I guess the buffer needs to store more than the dots, e.g. the blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't work out why this fixes it, or why it crashes in the first place but...)

If you remove the `window_destroy(s_main_window);` from your `deinit` function it won't crash any more.

Comment: Really? That's so weird. That bit of code was from the Pebble watch face tutorial on their site. Hmm. Thanks!

Comment: That function call isn't the cause of the issue, there's something about your watchface that causes it to crash if you leave it in. I checked our official examples and they all work fine, at some point I will try and track down exactly what the issue with yours is.